# Is the usage of main without a return type phased out in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Stephen Prata in his book C++ Primer Plus [p 31] says :

> Many existing programs use the classic C function header instead:
>   `main() // original C style`
>   
> Under classic C, omitting the return type
>   is the same as saying that the function is type int. However, C++ has
>   phased out that usage.

However The C++11 draft 3.6.1->2 says

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function
>   shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but
>   otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

**Test Result**

```
$ g++ -Werror=pedantic MainCheck.cpp -o MainCheck
MainCheck.cpp:3:6: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type [-Werror=pedantic]
 main()
$ # also means g++ don't conform to the standard
```

confirms that what Mr. Prata said is true when it comes to C++ standard.

Is there a clause in the C++11 draft that discourages the use of :

```
main() // that is without return type.
```

Is

> It shall have a return type of type int

itself such a clause?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I would assume that many implementation didn't follow requirement to maintain compatibility with Old C Programs.

Comment: `main() {}` is banned by the rules governing declarations. See [\[dcl.type\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#dcl.type-3) and [\[dcl.dcl\]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#11). Similar wording can be found in every published standard.

Comment: ISO/IEC 14882:1998 contains: §7 Declarations ¶7 _Only in function declarations for constructors, destructors, and type conversions can the_ decl-specifier-seq
_be omitted.78)_ — and footnote 78 says _The “implicit int” rule of C is no longer supported._  So, `main()` declared without the return type has never been a part of standard C++, but it was allowed roughly up until C++98 standard was created (and probably a bit longer for reasons of backwards compatibility).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thanks. It is clear now..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

ISO/IEC 14882:1998 contains:

> §7 **Declarations**
>
> ¶7 Only in function declarations for constructors, destructors, and type conversions can the *decl-specifier-seq*
> be omitted.<sup>78)</sup>

and footnote 78 says:

> The “implicit int” rule of C is no longer supported.

The same statements are in  ¶9 and footnote 89 in the C++11 standard.

So, `main()` declared without the return type has never been a part of standard C++, but it was allowed roughly up until C++98 standard was created (and probably a bit longer for reasons of backwards compatibility).

If you look in Stroustrup's "Design and Evolution of C++" (published 1994), §2.8 **The C Declaration Syntax** says:

> Allowing the type specifier to be omitted (meaning `int` by default) also led to complications. … The negative reaction to changes in this area from users was very strong. … I backed out the change.  I don't think I had a choice.  Allowing that implicit `int` is the source of many of the annoying problems with the C++ grammar today. … Finally, ten years later, the C++ ANSI/ISO standard committee has decided to deprecate implicit `int`.  That means we may get rid of it in another decade or so.

Answer (score 9):

Implicit `int` types were disallowed in all C++ standards, i.e., it wasn't allowed in C++98. It isn't anything new in C++11. There wasn't any exception for `main()` with respect to the *declaration* of the function. Also, the implicit `int` rule applied to all declarations not just to `main()`.

The relevant clause in the C++ standard is 7 [dcl.dcl] paragraph 11:

> Only in function declarations for constructors, destructors, and type conversions can the *decl-specifier-seq*
>   be omitted.<sup>94</sup>
>
> 94) The “implicit int” rule of C is no longer supported.

I don't have easy access to the C++98 standard right now but C++03 definitely has the same statement. The only difference is that it is in paragraph 7 and the footnote is "<sup>79</sup>" instead of "<sup>94</sup>".

C's implicit `int` rule was part of C++ for a while prior to the first standard but got removed at some point. Compilers may accept programs omitting the type as an extension but I think they are required to emit a diagnostic. Whether that means much is a separate question as it is long established that writing a single `\r` at the start of a line would meet that requirement.

What is there and what will remain is the odd exception that program execution can flow off the end of `main()` without a `return` statement: it is assumed that mandating a `return` statement in `main()` would break existing code.

The statement

> It shall have a return type of type `int`

doesn't state anything about how the function acquires its return type. It only states what the return type shall be.

Comment: Thanks, but I think compilers are not required to emit a diagnostic. For instance g++ won't

Comment: @sjsam I think so too.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main) is what the working draft says about the main function.
Excerpts follow.

- [3.6.1/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2)

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. Its type shall have C++ language linkage and it shall have a declared return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. An implementation shall allow both
>
> - a function of () returning int and
> - a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int
>
> as the type of main

- [3.6.1/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#5):

> A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function [...] If control flows off the end of the compound-statement of main, the effect is equivalent to a return with operand 0

So, the standard says that the main function shall have one of the following types:

- `int()`
- `int(int, char **)`

Being the main function a function, I guess it follows also the rules in [8.3.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct).
The question would become thus: *can I omit the return type from a function definition? Does the standard allow me to do that?*
The answer is no, indeed.

Comment: This is the only answer, realy answering the question. None of the other answers addresses the request for a proof in the standard.

Comment: @exilit: sadly, it doesn't address the question, though: the question is about the _declaration_ and **not** about the `return` statement, at least as written.

Comment: @exilit Except the quotes from the standard here don't actually answer the question. The question is about the implicit `int` return type.

Comment: @DietmarKühl And this answer is not about the `return` statement as well. It is about the return type. Which definetly is part of the declaration, no?

Comment: @DietmarKühl Actually, the answer is about both the return statement and the return type. Anyway, thanks for the comment. I guess the accepted answer is far better and I voted it up. :-)

Comment: @exilit There's nothing in the quotes in this answer that states that there is no implicit `int` return type, which was the point of the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza as skypjack said the accepted answer is much clearer. At time commenting this the other answer did not exist and I did not expected such a precise statement to exist in the standard. But nevertheless this answer contains two citations plus a third reference which the answerer used to conclude his statement.

Comment: @exilit There was at least one better answer when you posted your comment (otherwise I wouldn't have commented myself.) Plus I don't see how a number of largely irrelevant quotes from the standard "addresses the request for a proof in the standard".

Answer (score 2):

It is not required by the standard for the `main` to explicitly return. If `return` statement is missing, compiler simply puts:

`return 0;`

at the end. This rule doesn't apply to other functions.

In C, default return type of any function was `int` if not provided by programmer, for example:

```
get() // int assumed
{
    return 10;
}
```

C++ standard requires that you must specify the return type. Above code will not compile in C++ compiler. C90 allowed implicit `int`, C99 disallows implicit `int`.

Comment: By `By C++ doesn't allow it ` did you mean the standard doesn't allow it. Some implementation, say `g++` do allow it..

Comment: Yes, C++ standard requires explicit type to be given.

Comment: I think saying C++ doesn't allow it is clear enough, no one refers to any specific implementation of the C++ standard when they say "C++"

Comment: @xboi209 : But it is better to say which standard. Saying `C++` is not clear enough.

Comment: Actually, 'standard C++' is clear enough; it means C++98, C++03, C++11, C++14 all disallow it (and there's no reason to think any future version of C++ will allow it).